# How do I copy/paste cell values if the condition is true and enter "0" if the cell being looked at in the condition isn't there?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and I haven't been able to figure this out yet.

I need a code that copies cell `.Range("E" & i)` to cell `Sheets("CANmonitor").Range("C" & k)` if Column `B = 1731`.

However, it needs to look at `.Range("C" & i)` as well and set `Sheets("CANmonitor").Range("C" & K) = 0` if `.Range("C" & i)` is between `6` & `16` or between `28` & `39`.

To simplify, the value on column `C` jumps from `6` to `16` and from `28` to `39`. I need the code to enter `0s` for the missing values (ex: `1731.6` = data from `cell ("E" & i)` on sheet `DIC2`; `1731.7` = `0`). Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub DIC2toCAN()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, k As Long

    With Sheets("DIC2")
        LR = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        k = 1
        For i = 1 To LR
            With .Range("B" & i)
                If .Value = "1731" Then
                    If .Range("C" & i) is between 6 & 16 or is between 28 & 39 Then
                        Sheets("CANmonitor").Range("C" & k) = 0
                    Else
                        Sheets("DIC2").Range("E" & i).Copy _
                        Destination:=Sheets("CANmonitor").Range("C" & k)
                        k = k + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Care to explain the down vote? Other than poor formatting of the issue, it's actually pretty decent for a first post.

Comment: @pnuts - could be - I can't see VTC. Not sure I'd agree with the sentiment, but what do I know...

Comment: @pnuts (c) - thanks!  _blush_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code just a bit to correct a few things (formatting, missing dot, removed problematic With statement), and most importantly, I added the syntax for the "between" tests that you needed.

```
Sub DIC2toCAN()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, k As Long
With Sheets("DIC2")
    LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To LR
        If .Range("B" & i).Value = "1731" Then
            Dim test As Variant
            test = .Range("C" & i).Value
            If (test >= 6 And test <= 16) Or (test >= 28 And test <= 39) Then
                Sheets("CANmonitor").Range("C" & k) = 0
            Else
                Sheets("DIC2").Range("E" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("CANmonitor").Range("C" & k)
                k = k + 1
            End If
         End If
     Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is wonderful! It didn't work for me but I get what is being done here. This is giving me the same result that I've gotten while trying to figure it out. It seems as if it's not performing the test and just skipping to Else, which just copies over the values and I don't get the 0s. I'm supposed to have 50 parameters but I end up with only 31 because of the missing 19 values pointed out in the test variant. Also, the "k" should increment after each test, whether it copies the data or sets it to 0.

Comment: Guys, thank you so much. I think I know what the problem is. If  .Range("C" & i).Value is never equal to the values between 6 - 16 or 28 - 39, then it can't set it to zero. That's what I was missing..........I will never have those values so I just need to set them to zero when "k" equals any of the numbers in the range. I'll try to code it. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version. This code declares all the objects beforehand and then works with it. This way if later you need to change the sheet name, you do it at only one place. This code (**Untested**) also uses `Select Case` for simplicity.

```
Sub DIC2toCAN()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, k As Long
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

    '~~> Set your sheets here
    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DIC2")
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CANmonitor")

    With wsI
        LR = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        k = 1

        For i = 1 To LR
            '~~> Use Val to get the value
            If Val(.Range("B" & i).Value) = 1731 Then
                '~~> Use select case for simplicity
                Select Case Val(.Range("C" & i).Value)
                Case 6 To 16, 28 To 39
                    wsO.Range("C" & k).Value = 0
                Case Else
                    .Range("E" & i).Copy wsO.Range("C" & k)
                    k = k + 1
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddharth, it doesn't perform the tests and just goes to "case else." I don't get the zeros and i'm missing the 19 values (7-15 and 29-38).

Comment: Guys, thank you so much. I think I know what the problem is. If  .Range("C" & i).Value is never equal to the values between 6 - 16 or 28 - 39, then it can't set it to zero. That's what I was missing..........I will never have those values so I just need to set them to zero when "k" equals any of the numbers in the range. I'll try to code it. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are very, very close.

Change this:

```
If .Range("C" & i) is between 6 & 16 or is between 28 & 39 Then
```

to

```
If (.Range("C" & i) >= 6 and .Range("C" & i) <= 16) OR _
   (.Range("C" & i) >= 28 and .Range("C" & i) <=39) Then
```

Also, simplify this:

```
Sheets("DIC2").Range("E" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("CANmonitor").Range("C" & k)
```

to this:

```
Sheets("CANmonitor").Range("C" & k) = Sheets("DIC2").Range("E" & i)
```

It gives the same result, but requires less typing and is easier to read.

Comment: On replacing the Copy command with setting the value--you are assuming the value is the only thing the OP wanted to copy. If so, this is the better way. However, if the desire is to also copy formatting, then the original method is needed.

Comment: Rachel / FreeMan: You guys just explained why I kept getting the borders after I ran the macro!!! Thank you! I don't need the copy formatting, just the value.